# Replacing XPath string in xsl file

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have an XSL file with XPath which correspond to an XML file with UBL 2.0 standard and I need the XPath to fit UBL 2.1 standard.

The number of Files which need the change is too numerous, for that reason I'm trying to use the sed command to replace the XPath in each file. I have tried the next command:

```
sed -i 's/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID"\/>/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cac:Party\/cac:PartyIdentification\/cbc:ID"\/>/g' path/to/file
```

The XPath contains characters that need to be escaped, so my doubt is if I will have no problems with the replacement of the paths with the current structure of the command.

After running the command to obtain the output in another file:

```
sed -e 's/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID"\/>/select="\/ns1:Invoice\/cac:AccountingSupplierParty\/cac:Party\/cac:PartyIdentification\/cbc:ID"\/>/g' file > output
```

I obtain the output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 216: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Have you *tried* your command?  Try it (on a copy of a file, and/or without ``-i``) and see what happens.  Then, if you still have a question, tell us what happened when you ran the command, and explain what you still don’t understand.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Note that you are free to choose an other delimiter (instead of `/`) in sed for replacement commands: `s#pattern#replacement#`. This way you don't have to escape each slashes.

Answer (score 3):

When modifying XML files, `sed` really isn't the best choice as it has no clue that there is structure to the file being edited and will happily turn a well-formed document into badly-formed mush. Instead, you should use an XML-aware tool: I'll use `xsltproc` and XSLT, but an XML grep utility would likely do the job too.

First, [make a identity transformation stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615875/xslt-how-to-change-an-attribute-value-during-xslcopy) that replaces the old `select` attribute value with the new one:

**replace.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@select[contains(.,'/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="select">
    <xsl:value-of select="'/ns1:Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then run `xsltproc` on the file to be converted:

```
xsltproc replace.xslt /path/to/inputfile.xml > /path/to/convertedfile.xml
```

As usual, confirm that the transformation is doing the right thing; I went off of what you provided, so other changes may be required for a full conversion.